# Looping through filtered items in slicer

Tags: vba, excel, slicers

I am attempting to write a macro but am caught up. How do you create a loop that will loop through only visible objects in an already filtered slicer.

Image below is the slicer I want to use ("slicer_Route") and I only the loop to loop through the first 4 darkened objects. (These were the result of another filter)

SLICER:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to do but this goes through Visible Items:

```
Dim sC As SlicerCache
Dim sI As SlicerItem

Set sC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Route")

For Each sI in sC.SlicerItems
If sI.Selected = True Then

Debug.Print sI.Name 'This is an example, you can do what you want with that item

End If

Next sI
```

If you provide more detailed question, you may get further help.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by using the property HasData in sliceritems.